# Preciso de um novo número random a cada linha em uma consulta sql(server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, random

Utilizo o **sql server**. Preciso usar um número random em várias colunas diferentes(o mesmo número random) porém quero um novo numero random a cada linha...

por exemplo, vamos supor que a TABELAX possui apenas 5 linhas e eu faço uma consulta do gênero...

```
select numeroRandom,numeroRandom2 from TABELAX
```

eu quero  obter como resultado algo do gênero..

```
| numeroRandom | numeroRandom2 |
|______________|_______________|
|    1         |      1        |
|    5         |      5        |
|    8         |      8        |
|    2         |      2        |
|    1         |      1        |
```

Por favor, alguém me ajuda!!

Comment: Você quer um número de linha randômico? No seu exemplo seria de 1 a 5, é nesse intervalo que você quer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `row_number` que atribui um número de linha baseado em agregação ou ordenação, e utilizar a função `newid` como ordenação, que gera um valor único para cada linha a cada vez que a `query` é executada:

```
select row_number() over(order by newid()) as randomico1,
       row_number() over(order by newid()) as randomico2,
       ra
  from saluno
 order by ra
```

A `query` acima não funciona utilizando a cláusula `top`. Caso seja necessário utiliza-la, deve-se realizar uma `subquery` com o `top` antes de gerar a coluna randômica da seguinte forma:

```
select row_number() over(order by newid()) as randomico1,
       row_number() over(order by newid()) as randomico2,
       x.ra
 from (select top(10) tb.*
         from saluno tb) x
order by x.ra
```

Caso queira utilizar mais de uma vez o mesmo valor para outra coluna você também pode utilizar uma `subquery`:

```
select x.randomico1,
       x.randomico1 as randomico2,
       x.ra
  from (select row_number() over(order by newid()) as randomico1,
               tb.*
          from saluno tb) x
 order by x.ra
```

Ou:

```
select row_number() over(order by x.aleatorio) as randomico1,
       row_number() over(order by x.aleatorio) as randomico2,
       x.ra
  from (select newid() as aleatorio,
               tb.*
          from saluno tb) x
 order by x.ra
```

Caso queira um número randômico que não tenha relação com a quantidade de linhas, utilize a seguinte `query` em que o número após o `%`é o máximo:

```
select abs(checksum(newid()) % 10) + 1 as randomico1,
       ra
  from saluno
```

Ou utilizando para as duas colunas randômicas:

```
select x.aleatorio as randomico1,
       x.aleatorio as randomico2
  from (select cast(rand(checksum(newid())) * 10 as int) + 1 as aleatorio,
               tb.*
          from saluno tb) x
 order by x.ra
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
       x.aleatorio as randomico1,
       x.aleatorio as randomico2
  from (select CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10 as INT) + 1  as aleatorio,
               tb.*
          from saluno tb) x
 order by x.ra
```